# index action not ran in cakephp framework's first tutorial:blog in 15 minutes

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-model

i have a problem running cakephp in netbeans 8.0 in ubuntu.

When project is ran i get to see a page(index.php) @ localhost/blog1 that introduces and presents the : "CakePHP: the rapid development php framework" so the plugin works but i get to see file not found at the http://localhost/blog1/posts/index after i completed ~/View/Posts/index.ctp from the same 15' blog tutorial (book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/tutorials-and-examples/blog/blog.html)

I have to add that after i uncommented Configure::write('App.baseUrl', env('SCRIPT_NAME')) from core.php, as seen on another stackoverflow thread, the page localhost/blog1 started looking for app/Controller/Blog1Controller.php